# Redis error: "unknown command 'MULTI'" on Redis 1.2.6

Tags: redis, debian

I have an error `unknown command 'MULTI'` on Redis server 1.2.6, how is it possible as [the docs](http://redis.io/commands/multi) say that it's available since 1.2.0 ?

The distrib is Debian 6.

Comment: 1.2 is really extremely old. I would suggest to compile a recent version. Compiling Redis is straightforward.

Comment: Yes, finally, we used the backports repos to install 2.4, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

We finally installed 2.4 using backports repository. 
I'll write a comment on the docs' page though.